# how do I create a job that runs groovy code with the job dsl?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I can run this inside of a job dsl project:

```
def pluginsListFile = new File("${plugins}/plugins.txt")
def pluginsList = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
pluginsList.each {
    pluginsListFile.append "${it.getShortName()}: ${it.getVersion()}\n"
}
```

But I want the job dsl script to create a job that runs this groovy code (on a schedule). It looked like systemGroovyCommand is what I would use be I dont understand- looks like you have to use a .groovy *file* for systemGroovyCommand which i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's [systemGroovyCommand](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.MultiJobStepContext.systemGroovyCommand). You don't have to store this script in separate file, but it's a best practice.
`systemGroovyCommand` accepts string as parameter, so you can pass your code this way, but remember to escape special characters.

Example usage:

```
def script = '''
def pluginsListFile = new File("${plugins}/plugins.txt")
def pluginsList = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
pluginsList.each {
    pluginsListFile.append "${it.getShortName()}: ${it.getVersion()}\\n"
}
'''
job('TEST_JOB_SCRIPT') {
    steps {
        systemGroovyCommand(script)
    }
}
```